# SVN New User Credentials

Tags: svn, authentication

I have 2 local copies.  Each one is related to a different repository.

I insert the user name and password for the first local copy, related to `repository 1`, for example, and save the authentication.

When I create another local copy to `repository 2`, I would like to insert new credentials.

I do not like to clear all the authentication data.
I would like to save different authentications for different local copies on the same machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The normal behavior of SVN is already to remember the credentials separately for each repository. It will not try to use the credentials of repository A for repository B.

However, I've noticed that SVN users often confuse "SVN repository" with "project/folder inside a SVN repository". So perhaps you meant that you have two working copies of different folders in the *same* repository? In that case, what you are asking is not possible.